# LocalSocketIpcClient spy

Tags: c, multithreading, command-line-interface, ipc

I have differents processes running on Ubuntu.
They exchange information through LocalSocketIpcClient/Server.
I plannned to write a Spy program which could inject and listen to IPC messages.
This program use a thread with getch and putchar to handle user input in a small terminal (not GUI).
When a command line has been input, it is parsed and send to LocalSocketIpcServer : this is done through and endless loop in the same thread.
Another thread has its own LocalSocketIpcClient and display the message received with a simple printf function.
My problem is that I got unwanted '0' (0x30 ASCII) character that appear...
May be because of the the two thread writing on the same stdout ....

Is there another way, to have a program acting as a console line input/output , which could display incoming IPC message on the same console ?

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbOqN.jpg)
Thanks for any idea ...

Comment: What's `LocalSocketIpcClient`? Something [like this](https://github.com/smitp/bibref-qt/blob/master/LocalSocketIpcClient.h)?

Comment: @FelixPalmen : In some ways...